# Detecting content in a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to detect whether 3 divs are empty or not and if they all have some content activate a button.

```
function checkContent() 
{

    if (!$.trim($('#Div1').html()).length && !$.trim($('#Div2').html()).length &&    !$.trim($('#Div3').html()).length) 
     {
        console.log("Ready");
        $('#nextbutton').prop("disabled", false);
     } 
     else 
     {
        console.log("Not Ready");
     }
}
```

So I added some content to Div1, and the console reads, not ready. Some to div 2 still not ready. And some to div 3 (it should now be ready) but still says not ready.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove not condition from below

```
if ($.trim($('#Div1').html()).length > 0 && $.trim($('#Div2').html()).length > 0 && $.trim($('#Div3').html()).length > 0) {
       console.log("Ready")
       $('#nextbutton').prop("disabled", false);
   } else {
       console.log("Not Ready")
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter instead of making a long condition.

```
emptyDivs = $('[id^=div]').each(function(){
     return $.trim($(this).html()) == "";
});
if(emptyDivs.length == 0)
    $('#nextbutton').prop("disabled", false);
else 
    console.log("Not Ready")
```